# I like to Move it Move it

Tags: riddle

My prefix moves your body all over the world

My infix moves your heart if you have a good taste

My suffix moves your life on through a perilous journey

But my whole stays in place as people move in it's place

What am I?

Hint 1:

> Think of history

Comment: Is `if you have a good taste` implying the flavor of a human being?

Comment: hahah no, if you like the infix then it moves your heart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A guess since a letter remains unaccounted for, but are you:

> Carthage?

My prefix moves your body all over the world

> A car

My infix moves your heart if you have a good taste

> art

My suffix moves your life on through a perilous journey

> age

But my whole stays in place as people move in it's place

> Carthage was a large historical city.  Though it's been destroyed, people have moved to and from it's site until modern times.

Comment: Yep, this is correct, congrats